# C++ QT: QSqlQuery::prepare: database not open

Tags: c++, sql, qt, sqlite

Sorry in advance for any apparent overlap of questions, but I have searched what feels like every possible question on this site for an answer to my problem and none of them have worked. The main issue is that I cannot seem to open my SQLITE3 database in order to search it and display to a QTableView. My code is below:

```
void MainWindow::on_searchBButton_clicked() {
qDebug() << QSqlDatabase::drivers();

//Setup the search query and open database
//toolboxData = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
//toolboxData.setDatabaseName(":/Resources/Resources/ToolSearch.db");
QString searchStr;
searchStr = ui->basicSearchInput->text();

//Filter out any hyphens
for (int i = 0; i < searchStr.length(); ++i) {
    if (searchStr[i] == QLatin1Char('-')) searchStr[i] = QLatin1Char(' ');
}

//Do the actual searching now
QString sQry;

QSqlQueryModel *model = new QSqlQueryModel();

QSqlDatabase toolboxDb = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
//toolboxDb.setDatabaseName(":/Resources/Resources/ToolSearch.db");
toolboxDb.setDatabaseName("C:\\New folder\\ToolSearch.db");
bool db_ok = toolboxDb.open();

if (!QFile::exists("C:\\New folder\\ToolSearch.db"))
    qDebug() << "This file does not exist";

if (!db_ok)
    qDebug() << "Connection Failed\n";

QSqlQuery *qry = new QSqlQuery(toolboxDb);

sQry += "SELECT * FROM ToolSearch WHERE keywords MATCH :searchTerm UNION SELECT * FROM ToolSearch WHERE name MATCH :searchTerm UNION ";
sQry += "SELECT * FROM ToolSearch WHERE category MATCH :searchTerm UNION SELECT * FROM ToolSearch WHERE subcategory MATCH :searchTerm ";
sQry += "UNION SELECT * FROM ToolSearch WHERE sources MATCH :searchTerm UNION SELECT * FROM ToolSearch WHERE usagetype :searchTerm UNION ";
sQry += "SELECT * FROM ToolSearch WHERE cost MATCH :searchTerm";

qry->prepare(sQry);

//Add the necessary single quotes to the given string
searchStr = '\'' + searchStr + '\'';

qry->bindValue(":searchTerm", searchStr);

qry->exec();
model->setQuery(*qry);
ui->searchResults->setModel(model);
ui->searchResults->show(); }
```

Most of the answers that I saw on here said that to open the database you have to write something along the lines of the following:

```
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
db.setDatabaseName("C:\\SomeFolder\\SomeFile.db");
bool db_ok = db.open();
```

However, I have almost the exact same code in mine for opening the database and even tested it with an absolute address as opposed to the relative address I had with the ":/Resources/Resources/ToolSearch.db" line. Also, the output of qDebug() << QSqlDatabase::drivers() gives:

("QSQLITE", "QMYSQL", "QMYSQL3", "QODBC", "QODBC3", "QPSQL", "QPSQL7")

Lastly, I have also used verified that the file does exist at the location I am trying to open it at using the if (!QFile::exists()) statement. So, I am at a loss for why this is not working. The specific error message that I get when I attempt to run this code is "QSqlQuery::prepare: database not open".

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You do **not** have the same code. And the error message tells you exactly which line is missing.

Comment: Sorry, I had that line and for some reason had deleted it previously because it wasn't working beforehand. However, when I re-added the bool db_ok = db.open() line with the absolute address (C:\\NewFolder\\ToolSearch.db) it works, but when I change it to the Relative Address (:\\Resources\\Resources\\ToolSearch.db) it fails even though I still check if the file exists and it does. So that seems to narrow down the problem to something with accessing the database in the resources folder, but then the problem still remains because I need it to be relative. Any ideas?

Comment: That path is neither relative nor valid.

Comment: I don't see why the path is not valid though since I go to my resources.qrc file, directly copied the path to my clipboard from there, and then pasted it into the code. I also did this earlier with an image using the line: QPixmap imagePix(":/Resources/Resources/image.png"); and it worked just fine. When I built an earlier version of the project and then ran it on another machine, it also ran just fine accessing the file from that path which is the same path where I am trying to access the database at. Also, the QFile::exists line still says that the file I am looking for does exist there.

Comment: The error messages tells you that the database is not open, so where exactly do you think you have opened the database int the code you posted? Further if opening the _database_ fails, `QSqlDatabase` provides methods to get the latest error.

Comment: That path might be valid for `QFile`, but SQLite itself does not use Qt.

Comment: That solved the issue. I had just assumed Qt would enable SQLite would allow for the database to be opened from the .qrc file. I actually made it relative without the Qt libraries. Everything is working now thanks!